# Create wordpress plugin ( PHPexcel )

Tags: php, wordpress

i have code PHP for read Excel file, im using PHPexcel and i want make a plugin for wordpress to show my data from excel. Running on Localhost is worked perfectly, but running on my site is not work, when click submit there is a just blank content, trying in another template is same.

Here my code :

```
add_shortcode('show_number', 'find');

function find(){
?>
<form method="post" action="">
Number : <input type="text" name="number" /><button type="submit">Find</button>
</form>


<?php
    if (isset($_POST['number']) {
    $number = $_POST["number"];

    require_once ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). 'includes\classes\PHPExcel.php');
    $tmpfname = ( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). 'number.xlsx');
    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
    $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    $excel_arr = $worksheet->toArray(null,true,true,true);

        for ($row=1;$row <=$lastRow;$row++){

             if ($excel_arr[$row]["A"] == $number ) {
               echo $excel_arr[$row]["A"];
               break;
             }
        }
   }
}
```

if i delete code for read Excel to be :

```
function find(){
?>
<form method="post" action="">
Number : <input type="text" name="number" /><button type="submit">Find</button>
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['number']) {
    $number = $_POST["number"];

    echo $number;
}
```

The page load normaly, and display $number. I think I misapplied PHPexcel code for wordpress plugin

Solved :    Avoid to use "\" to describe paths

Comment: Avoid to use \ to describe paths, this symbol can also be interpreted as an escape sequence. Use `/` instead.

Comment: Look in the log files on your web server. There you will find the error message you're not seeing. Also, as Havenard says, it's better to use `/`. My guess would be that this is the problem: are you using Windows locally (which would be okay with "\"?) and Unix for your server (which would *not* be okay with "\"?) (It shouldn't be an escaping problem, though, as "\" will be treated as a literal backslash in your single-quoted string.)

Comment: (You could also consider temporarily enabling [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) in your server version of WordPress.)

Comment: Thank you Havenard and Matt, you solved my problem,
you are right Matt, i'm using Windows Locally so using "\" is no problem.

btw how to give to you reputation ?

Comment: @IrfanFauzi I'll post an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just a couple of problems:

1. Your server is set not to display errors, which is why you get a blank screen rather than a useful error message. Check your server error logs, and consider enabling [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) in WordPress, at least temporarily.
2. You're using a backslash as a directory separator. This will work on Windows machines (I'm guessing your local machine is Windows), but not on Unix machines (which I'm guessing your server is.) Try using a forward slash ("/") as the path separator instead. This will work on both platforms.

(If you really want to go belt and braces, you can use the PHP constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, but that can be overkill and make your code harder to read. Most people just stick to forward slashes.)